# Maximal abelian extension of finite abelian Galois extension of local fields of characteristic 0

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, local-field

Let $K$ be a non-archimedean local field of characteristic $0$. One might take a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ for some prime $p$. We fix an algebraic closure of $K$, and, throughout, every extension of $K$ is in that fixed algebraic closure.  Let $L$ be a finite abelian Galois extension of $K$. I am wondering if there is any known relation between the maximal abelian extensions $L^{ab}$ of $L$ and $K^{ab}$ of $K$. For example, do we have $K^{ab}\subset L^{ab}$? If then, can we expect $\operatorname{Gal}(L/K)\simeq\operatorname{Gal}(L^{ab}/K^{ab})$?

Comment: Did you show the isomorphism between $Gal(E/F)$ and $F^\times / N_{E/F}(E^\times)$ ?

Comment: @reuns How is it related to my question?

Comment: A compositum of finite Galois extensions is Galois – it follows formally that a compositum of finite abelian extensions is abelian and then that $L \subset K^{ab} \subset L^{ab}$. Of course, the reverse implication is false: take $K=\mathbb{Q}_p$, $L=\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_p)$, then $p^{1/p} \in L^{ab}$ but $p^{1/p} \notin K^{ab}$. In this case, $[L(p^{1/p}):L]$ has degree $p$, which is coprime to the order of $Gal(L/K)$.